PostgreSQL connection string error on Payload cms
Payload Version
"payload": "^2.0.0"
Node Version
node:18.8-alpine
Next.js Version
"next": "13.5.2"
Bug
When I run yarn build I got this error:
[12:41:39] ERROR (payload): Error: cannot connect to Postgres. Details: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

This is my database uri:
DATABASE_URI="postgres://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${DB_NAME}"

This question is similar to: What is the format for the PostgreSQL connection string / URL?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's not a connection string problem, it's a db connection on build problem. Payload problem

Add the client ID to your build command:
flutter build web --dart-define=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com
flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com

In the Dart code:
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  clientId: const String.fromEnvironment('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
);

Ensure the meta tag is in web/index.html:
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">

This should properly pass and read the GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID.

This should not findin postgres server. check hostname and credentials. maybe docker issue?

I'm not usign flutter with dart. I'm using payload with typescript
